# Create groups based on countries in dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a csv file and one of the field is country which have list of countries.

How to do a pie chart named as continents (not in my csv field) and i need to group the countries to continents in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a mapping from countries to continents, something like:

```
var continent = {
    USA: 'North America',
    France: 'Europe',
    Belgium: 'Europe',
    India: 'Asia',
    China: 'Asia',
    Kenya: 'Africa'
    // ...
};
```

Then you can define your dimension to key on continents instead of countries by using the map:

```
var cf = crossfilter(data);
var continentDimension = cf.dimension(d => continents[d.country]),
    continentGroup = continentDimension.group();
```

And the rest is as usual; take a look at the [pie chart example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/pie.html) for some hints on configuring the chart.

Comment: Thanks much Gordon, i will try this out and accept the answer.

Comment: Hey @Sakthi did it work? Please click the green checkmark by the answer if it did. Besides giving me a few Fake Internet Points™ it also helps people who follow tags know what questions to look at. Thanks!